# How to back Ruby on Rails models to only ElasticSearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have been looking for a while and could not find information about how to create a Ruby on Rails application that uses just ElasticSearch as a backend.

Can anyone show me the way to use the ElasticSearch gems available to back a model in a ruby on rails application to only ElasticSearch?

All of the solutions I find involve backing data to a relational database like MySQL and then updating ElasticSearch on callbacks/hooks. I was trying to avoid having the data in two places, would like all data to live in ElasticSearch.

I envisions something like this:

```
class Person < ElasticSearch::ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Where `ElasticSearch::ActiveRecord::Base` will back the model to ElasticSearch.

Comment: I am a bit unclear as to what you are asking but have you looked at [`elasticsearch-model`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model) or you could just write your own simple dsl for [`elasticsearch-api`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-api)

Comment: I looked at elasticsearch-model which looks like its just callbacks, data is written to both ES and another database. Someone did show me how active model is where I should be looking and not active record, in active model it seems like I can use elasticsearch-api and similar gems